# Can't connect to wifi14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, internet

I recently moved back home, and for some reason my laptop can't connect to my wifi.It used to connect to it after some time, but now it just stopped. I have an ASUS Q501LA.

Any help would be much appreciated

Edit: also the only way to connect to the internet is via ethernet connection

Comment: Reinstall the driver package: `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove linux-firmware-nonfree && sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. It shows that i connected to the network, but it doesn't connect, and it also keeps asking me to re-enter my wifi password (I know what it is and i enter it correctly every time)

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do

Comment: thanks, here is the link:
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7869758/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the wep encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

If your router is capable of N speeds, it is better to use a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz.

Second set your wireless channel in the router to 1 or 11 then save the router configuration and reboot it.

Third go into network manager at top right corner of the screen and click on edit connections>wireless tab and set IPV6 to ignore.

Fourth turn power management off:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

(this will create or edit a configuration file that will override the default power management behavior) and enter the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

above exit0, then save gedit, close and reboot.