# 14.04 Wifi Unstable

Tags: wireless, 14.04, intel-wireless

Wifi will repeatedly cut out after an undetermined amount of time.

I've read the [Unstable wireless connection in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504777/unstable-wireless-connection-in-ubuntu-14-04)
but I don't want to disable N mode b/c I want the faster speed.

I have this card: http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/wireless/cwn-1030

I also tried turning off power management but that doesn't work either

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

I ran the wifi script

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script
```

Here are the results: http://pastebin.com/1AdPQy7D

Comment: If you tried everything in that other post except the commands that were specific to the driver in that post then N speed being disabled is the last step, because I think there is still a bug that is not allowing new drivers to be built on the newer kernel. N speed most of the time has to be disabled until the driver gets better but it does depend on the router you are using.

Comment: Here is a link that may help without disabling N speed.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/503128/cant-connect-to-wifi14-04/503173#503173

Answer (score 1):

There may be some code missing in the kernel. See the following "LTR patch".
Updating to the patched kernel may be the solution. 
(See [here for an example](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/08/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-3-16/) how to do this.)

kV.

---

[See: LTR Patch](http://people.canonical.com/~sforshee/iwl-ltr/trusty/)

[PATCH] iwlwifi: configure the LTR

"From eaf90486817fd0c3de2c65d51e9f2841ec352624 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001

From: Emmanuel Grumbach  
Date: Tue, 23 Sep 2014 23:02:41 +0300

Subject: [PATCH] iwlwifi: configure the LTR

The LTR is the handshake between the device and the root
complex about the latency allowed when the bus exits power
save. This configuration was missing and this led to high
latency in the link power up. The end user could experience
high latency in the network because of this."

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me.

In "network Connections" configuration, for my wifi, in "IPv6 settings", I simply selected "Ignore".

Since then, no disconnections. I hope that help others